# Minified 0 images in grunt imagemin:dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to minify the images but it says:

> Minified 0 images.

If I change the value of the `src` property to: `['**/.*{png,gif,jpg,jpeg}']` - it minifies the `node_modules` folder and the images in there.

The *Gruntfile.js* is in the same path as the folder img.

Some help please?

```
        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './',
                    src: 'img/*.{png, gif, jpg, jpeg}',
                    dest: 'dist/'
                }]
            }
        },
```